# Is there a way to input values on a web site's text box using a database table values?

Tags: java, php, javascript

I have a table with username and passwords that I want to input in Hotmail's username and password box. Is there a way to actually program this? Are you allowed to manipulate text boxes of someone else's webpage? Not for illegal purposes, just to make my job easier and to not have to input values manually one by one. Hotmail is just an example.

Comment: sorry i'm a new programmer and i'm just trying out things.

Comment: Most probably Hotmail will present you with a captcha if script-like behavior is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but it's probably a very bad idea.

First of all, you are introducing security problems. First you had a username and a password, and they were in your head only. The attack surface is small: with the exception of social engineering, a combination of at least two attacks is required, e.g. man-in-the-middle *and* a compromised SSL certificate. If, however, you write your tool, you'll have a whole database server, probably with a web server on top, and some javascript to access it. Compromise any of those parts, and there's all your passwords. It's probably not even hard to exploit: if your javascript is out in the open, then all it takes to get to your password is to run that javascript on a different page and have it submit a form there (ideally in a hidden iframe so you never get to see it happening). While it is unlikely that an attacker targets you specifically, if they do, the consequences are disastrous.

And then there's the legal side. In many countries, 'hacking' is illegal, even without criminal intent. What constitutes hacking is rather ill-defined, and things like disabling javascript to get around client-side validation have been found to be punishable in the past. While your intent is innocent, the technique, although unlikely to be detected, could, in extreme cases, be considered hacking.

And finally; there are solutions that can already do this, although they don't use an SQL database. Look for form filler plugins; there's plenty of them for most major browsers, just pick one that suits your preferences.